# Send int on socket as byte[] then recast to int not works

Tags: java, sockets, casting, nio

I'm trying to serialize Object between NIO SocketChannel and blocking IO Socket. Since I can't use Serializable/writeObject on NIO, I thought to write code to serialize object into an ByteArrayOutputStream then send array length followed by array.

Sender function is

```
public void writeObject(Object obj) throws IOException{
    ByteArrayOutputStream serializedObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(serializedObj);
    writer.writeUnshared(obj);
    ByteBuffer size =        ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(serializedObj.toByteArray().length);

    this.getSocket().write(size);
    this.getSocket().write(ByteBuffer.wrap(serializedObj.toByteArray()));
}
```

and receiver is:

```
public Object readObject(){
    try {
        //Leggi dimensione totale pacchetto
        byte[] dimension = new byte[4];

        int byteRead = 0;

        while(byteRead < 4) {
            byteRead += this.getInputStream().read(dimension, byteRead, 4 - byteRead);
        }

        int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(dimension).getInt(); /* (*) */
        System.out.println(size);

        byte[] object = new byte[size];

        while(size > 0){
            size -= this.getInputStream().read(object);
        }

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(object, 0, object.length);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        Object res = ois.readUnshared();
        ois.close();
        return res;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that size (*) is always equals to -1393754107 when serializedObj.toByteArray().length in my test is 316. 
I don't understand why casting not works properly.

Comment: Casting? What casting?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.getSocket().write(size);
this.getSocket().write(ByteBuffer.wrap(serializedObj.toByteArray()));
```

If the result of `getSocket()` is a `SocketChannel` in non-blocking mode, the problem is here. You aren't checking the result of `write()`. In non-blocking mode it can write less than the number of bytes remaining in the `ByteBuffer`; indeed it can  write zero bytes.

So youu aren't writing all the data you think you're writing, so the other end overruns and reads the next length word as part of the data being written, and reads part of the next data as the next length word, and gets a wrong answer. I'm surprised it didn't barf earlier. In fact it probably did, but your deplorable practice of ignoring `IOExceptions` masked it. Don't do that. *Log* them.

So you need to loop until all requested data has been written, and if any `write()` returns zero you need to select on OP_WRITE until it fires, which adds a considerable complication into your code as you have to return to the select loop while remembering that there is an outstanding `ByteBuffer` with data remaining to be written. And when you get the OP_WRITE and the writes complete you have to *deregister* interest in OP_WRITE, as it's only of interest after a `write()` has returned zero.

NB There is no casting in your code.

Comment: Now the IOException on caller is not masked. It print stack trace, but it is never throw.

Comment: write() returns 0. Always.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was write() returned 0 always. This happens because the buffer wasn't flipped before write().